# Error - End of statement expected when doing math calculations in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, vb.net, variables

This is my idea:

1. You import a file with some basic math questions
2. You read the file and copy what's written in it to a label

But when I try to calculate I am having a problem,

This is an example of the code I am having:

```
    Dim Five As Integer = 5
    Dim Six As Integer = 6
    Dim Plus As String = "+"
    If Five Plus Six = 9 then

    End If
```

When I move my mouse over the code it says:

> End of statement expected

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use a string as an operator just because the string happens to be the same character. What does it do if you change it to `If Five + Six = 9 Then`?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. How will `5 + 6` ever be equal to `9`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try parsing for your operator. Something like this:

```
Private Function doCalcs() As String

    Dim Five As Integer = 5
    Dim Six As Integer = 6
    Dim Plus As String = "+"
    Dim result As Integer

    Select Case Plus
        Case "+"
            result = Five + Six
        Case "-"
            result = Five - Six
        Case Else
            result = -1 'or error handler
    End Select

    Return result

End Function
```

Comment: Mark as the answer if you're happy with it :)

Comment: forgot that, new on stackoverflow.